# Python Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax | Arduino Serial

Tags: python, mysql, sql, arduino, syntax-error

Everytime it runs it gives me this error.

```
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME())' at line 2
```

Query gets the data from an arduino via USB. A few days ago it worked flawlessly with a keypad to test if it works, until I tried getting the IDs with an RFID reader. I only changed the column ID to SN to match the Database. If I put the ID directly into the query it magically works. I don't know if it has something to do with the code on my arduino.

Python code:

```
while True:
    data = arduino.readline().decode('ascii')
    if data != '': 
        print(data)
        
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `Anwesenheit` (SN, Datum, Uhrzeit) VALUES ({}, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME());".format(data))
        db.commit()
```

Previous Arduino code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

String nummer;


byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; 
byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; 

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop(){
  
  char key = customKeypad.getKey();

  if (key){
   // Serial.println(key);
    if(key == '*') {
      nummer = ""; 
    } else if(key == '#') {
      
        Serial.println(nummer);
        nummer = "";
        
    } else {
      nummer += key;
    }
  }
}
```

Arduino Code now:

```
#include <Wiegand.h>
#define PIN_D1 3

Wiegand wiegand;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  wiegand.onReceive(receivedData, "");
  wiegand.onReceiveError(receivedDataError, "Card read error: ");
  wiegand.onStateChange(stateChanged, "");
  wiegand.begin(Wiegand::LENGTH_ANY, true);

  pinMode(PIN_D0, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_D1, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN_D0), pinStateChanged, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PIN_D1), pinStateChanged, CHANGE);
  
  pinStateChanged();
}
void loop() {
  noInterrupts();
  wiegand.flush();
  interrupts();
  delay(100);
}

// When any of the pins have changed, update the state of the wiegand library
void pinStateChanged() {
  wiegand.setPin0State(digitalRead(PIN_D0));
  wiegand.setPin1State(digitalRead(PIN_D1));
}

// Notifies when a reader has been connected or disconnected.
// Instead of a message, the seconds parameter can be anything you want -- Whatever you specify on `wiegand.onStateChange()`
void stateChanged(bool plugged, const char* message) {
    Serial.print(message);
    Serial.println(plugged ? "" : "DISCONNECTED");
}

// Notifies when a card was read.
// Instead of a message, the seconds parameter can be anything you want -- Whatever you specify on `wiegand.onReceive()`
void receivedData(uint8_t* data, uint8_t bits, const char* message) {
    
    //Serial.print(bits);
    //Serial.print("bits / ");
    //Print value in HEX
    uint8_t bytes = (bits+7)/8;
    for (int i=0; i<bytes; i++) {
        Serial.print(data[i] >> 4, 16);
        Serial.print(data[i] & 0xF, 16);
    }
    Serial.println();
}

// Notifies when an invalid transmission is detected
void receivedDataError(Wiegand::DataError error, uint8_t* rawData, uint8_t rawBits, const char* message) {
    Serial.print(message);
    Serial.print(Wiegand::DataErrorStr(error));
    Serial.print(" - Raw data: ");
    Serial.print(rawBits);
    Serial.print("bits / ");

    //Print value in HEX
    uint8_t bytes = (rawBits+7)/8;
    for (int i=0; i<bytes; i++) {
        Serial.print(rawData[i] >> 4, 16);
        Serial.print(rawData[i] & 0xF, 16);
    }
    Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: What are possible values of `data` in python code?

Comment: Never construct the query text in `cursor.execute`. Use intermediate variable. If error occures then investigate SQL text for the problem described in error message.

Comment: With the keypad i've only sent number, but the rfid reader sents out a Combination of Numbers and letters.

Answer (score 1):

the `data` value gets formatted into the string without the quotes, breaking the SQL syntax. Using bind variables will take care of this problem (and also protect your code against SQL injection attacks if the data can't be trusted):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `Anwesenheit` (SN, Datum, Uhrzeit) VALUES (%s, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), (data,))
```